# Finding the eigenvalues (diagonalizing) of a block-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a large $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix. It is the exact Hamiltonian of a spin chain model which I have generated with code I wrote in Fortran. The code block diagonalizes the Hamiltonian into constant total-spin sectors and furthermore into blocks of definite momentum. I wish to diagonalize it (find the eigenvalues), however when I import it into Mathematica and apply `Eigenvalues[]` to it, it takes a very long time. I assume that it would be much much faster to just compute the eigenvalues  of each block individually (currently modifying my Fortran code to separate these blocks). For example, for $N=10$ the matrix is $1028\times 1028$, but the largest block is $25\times 25$ and there are (I think) N(N+1) = 110 blocks, most of which are maybe $5\times 5$. Is there a way to indicate to Mathematica that the matrix is block diagonal, or an efficient way to do this without actually putting each block in a separate file and importing and diagonalizing all of them separately?

Note that the matrix is Hermitian and may be complex.

Comment: "when I import it into Mathematica" - is it a `SparseArray[]` when you import it?

Comment: I imported it as a table, I tried converting it to a `SparseArray[]` before passing it to `Eigenvalues[]` but I got a message which said that it was being converted back into a normal matrix because it would be faster. I am currently modifying my code so that it can be stored as a sparse array since only around ~1% of the matrix elements are non-zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possible approach. First, a random matrix that can be sorted into a block diagonal matrix (so that you don't have to worry about converting it to block diagonal form when importing):

```
sa = With[{perm=PermutationList[RandomPermutation[50],50]},
    SparseArray @ ArrayFlatten[
        DiagonalMatrix[Table[a,10]] /. a :> RandomReal[1,{5,5}]
    ][[perm,perm]]
];
```

Here is a view of the nonzero elements:

```
ArrayPlot[sa]
```

[image]

Now, we can use [`AdjacencyGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph) to convert to a graph, and then `ConnectComponents` to find the blocks:

```
blocks = ConnectedComponents @ AdjacencyGraph @ Unitize @ sa
```

> {{22, 26, 32, 39, 40}, {20, 25, 28, 31, 37}, {13, 16, 17, 45, 46}, {12, 14, 
>     29, 42, 49}, {9, 19, 33, 41, 50}, {7, 21, 30, 34, 43}, {6, 8, 24, 35, 
>     47}, {3, 4, 27, 38, 44}, {2, 10, 15, 23, 48}, {1, 5, 11, 18, 36}}

Finally, we can use these blocks to find the eigenvalues:

```
eigs = Eigenvalues[sa[[#, #]]]& /@ blocks
```

> {{1.99765 + 0. I, 
>     0.658726 + 0. I, -0.412903 + 0.13731 I, -0.412903 - 0.13731 I, 
>     0.253 + 0. I}, {2.84384 + 0. I, -0.75531 + 0. I, 0.261846 + 0.53826 I, 
>     0.261846 - 0.53826 I, 0.170376 + 0. I}, {2.23096, 0.481537, 
>     0.240699, -0.220823, 0.0584065}, {1.79549 + 0. I, -0.32683 + 0. I, 
>     0.113261 + 0.30506 I, 
>     0.113261 - 0.30506 I, -0.0047193 + 0. I}, {2.52376 + 0. I, -0.80018 + 0. I, 
>     0.492073 + 0.32248 I, 
>     0.492073 - 0.32248 I, -0.300104 + 0. I}, {2.95724 + 0. I, -0.534463 + 0. I, 
>     0.215221 + 0.394219 I, 
>     0.215221 - 0.394219 I, -0.0152984 + 0. I}, {2.46332 + 0. I, -0.594371 + 
>      0. I, 0.0462041 + 0.1835 I, 0.0462041 - 0.1835 I, 
>     0.106778 + 0. I}, {2.26045 + 0. I, -0.917553 + 0. I, 0.100373 + 0.481719 I, 
>     0.100373 - 0.481719 I, 0.423527 + 0. I}, {2.25639 + 0. I, 
>     0.34116 + 0.468159 I, 0.34116 - 0.468159 I, 
>     0.458043 + 0. I, -0.0805449 + 0. I}, {2.4259 + 0. I, -0.334963 + 
>      0.331565 I, -0.334963 - 0.331565 I, 0.462109 + 0. I, -0.109226 + 0. I}}

Let's compare with using [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues) directly on the matrix:

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance=4},
    Sort@Eigenvalues[sa] == Sort@Flatten@eigs
]
```

> True

Comment: ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` is cool. Never knew about that one.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think so too. It allows one to use the more instructive equal comparison instead of checking that the max of the absolute value of the differences is small.

Comment: @b3m2a1, for reference, there's also ``Internal`$SameQTolerance``.

Comment: wow I did not know about pretty much any of these functions haha, I need to take some time to understand how this works and how to apply it to my problem. Thank you. `ConnectedComponents` is pretty darn cool.

Comment: A shorter, but *undocumented* way to get the connected components: `Union[sa["AdjacencyLists"]]`

Comment: Are undocumented functions/features in testing before being added to the documentation? There seem to be quite a few

Comment: This is fantastic, about 100 times faster than blindly applying `Eigenvalues[]` directly to the matrix. Thanks!

Comment: Next question: why isn't there an option in `Eigenvalues[]` for this?

Comment: I made good experience with ``SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents`` for finding connected components in a matrix. It is usually much faster than first converting the matrix to a graph with `AdjacencyGraph`.